# Статические методы в родительском классе и наследнике

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, static, полиморфизм

Есть код:

```
public class Coffee {
    String name="Кофе";

    public static void buyCoffee(Coffee coffee) {
        System.out.println("Вы купили " + coffee.name);
    }
}

public class Latte extends Coffee{
    String name = "Латте";

    public static void buyCoffee(Coffee coffee) {
        System.out.println("Вы купили " + coffee.name);
    }
}

import static filosofia.java.p212.inheritance.static_method.Latte.buyCoffee;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        Latte latte = new Latte();
        buyCoffee(latte);
    }
}
```

Который выводит следующий результат

```
Вы купили Кофе
```

Я знаю, что статические методы не поддерживают полиморфное поведение, поэтому вывод `Вы купили Кофе` для объекта `Coffee coffee = new Latte()` было бы ожидаемо.
Но почему на объект `Latte latte = new Latte()` java реагирует как на объект типа Coffee не понятно. Т.е. при отсутствии созданного экземпляра класса `Coffee` программа все равно обратится к его полю. Как такое может быть?

Comment: потому что ваши `name` и Кофе и Латте никак не взаимосвязаны. это абослютно 2 разных поля. используйте `ovveride`

Comment: @Wlad, аннотация `@Override` нужна только компилятору для проверки, что такой метод есть в родительском классе. Отсутствие/присутствие аннотации в итоговом коде не будет иметь значения, если не допущены ошибки в именах.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то аннотация @Override не применима к полям, только к методам. Но в данном случае методы static, их переопределить тоже не получится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поля классов нельзя "переопределить" (override), только методы экземпляра.

Поскольку и в классе родителя `Coffee`, и в классе-потомке `Latte` определены поля с одинаковым именем `name`, при прямом обращении к такому полю (без виртуального геттера) будет возвращаться значение, соответствующее *типу ссылки на данный экземпляр*.  То есть, переменная `name` будет браться из того класса, тип которого указан в *параметре метода*, а не из типа своей ссылки.

> *Т.е. при отсутствии созданного экземпляра класса `Coffee` программа все равно обратится к его полю*

При вызове конструктора `new Latte()` будет вызван конструктор родительского класса по умолчанию `new Coffee()`, который "создаст" поле родителя, к которому будет доступ через тип ссылки:

```
new Latte() 
    -> new Coffee() 
       {name = "Coffee"}
{name = "Latte"}
```

Для вывода названия `Latte` потребуется "перегрузить" (overload) метод, чтобы он принимал аргумент типа `Latte`:

```java
class Coffee {
    String name = "Кофе";
    
    public static void buyCoffee(Coffee coffee) {
        System.out.println("Coffee: Вы купили " + coffee.name);
    }
}

class Latte extends Coffee {
    String name = "Латте"; // скрывает поле в классе-родителе

    public static void buyCoffee(Coffee coffee) {
        System.out.println("Latte: coffee: Вы купили " + coffee.name);
    }
    
    public static void buyCoffee(Latte latte) {
        System.out.println("Latte: latte: Вы купили " + latte.name);
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
Coffee coffee = new Coffee();
Latte.buyCoffee(coffee);       // buyCoffee(Coffee)

Coffee coffeeLatte = new Latte();
Latte.buyCoffee(coffeeLatte);  // buyCoffee(Coffee)

Latte latte = new Latte();
Latte.buyCoffee(latte);        // buyCoffee(Latte)
```

Результат

```
Latte: coffee: Вы купили Кофе
Latte: coffee: Вы купили Кофе
Latte: latte: Вы купили Латте
```

---

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. С перегрузкой метода интересное решение, как раз была мысль как же вывести строку "Вы купили Латте", перегрузка это решает. И еще как вывод: наверное лучше не использовать одинаковые имена переменных для разных классов. Спасибо!

Comment: _лучше не использовать одинаковые имена переменных для разных классов_, разумеется так, только уточнение -- в одной иерархии классов :), так как это фактически приводит к дублированию кода и нежелательным побочным эффектам, как в данном случае.

Answer (score 0):

Определение перекрывающихся переменных происходит на основе типа, который имеет переменная, а не реальный тип объекта. Это отличается от методов, которые наоборот определяются типом реального объекта, а не типом переменной.

Поскольку у вас стоит изменение типа в статическом методе с Latte на Coffee, то будет произведено обращение к родительскому классу.

```
public class Parent {
    String name = "Parent";
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    String name = "Child";
}

Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
Parent childWithTypeParent = new Child();

System.out.println(parent.name); // Parent
System.out.println(child.name); // Child
System.out.println(childWithTypeParent.name); // Parent
```

Следовательно, поменяв код на

```
public class Latte extends Coffee{
    String name = "Латте";

    public static void buyCoffee(Latte latte) {
        System.out.println("Вы купили " + latte.name);
    }
}
```

Вы получите вывод "Вы купили Латте".